# Нет прав в докер, на создание файлов

Tags: linux, битрикс, docker-compose

Вопрос есть развёрнутый локально проект в Docer контейнере, надо программно загружать файлы, отдает ошибку не может сохранить фалы, проект на битриксе. Права на компе стоят нормальные, комп Linux

Права Docer CLI
[image: Права на папки в CLI]

[image: Права на upload]

Comment: Ну а там волумы на рв примонтировать - тоже не пускает?

Comment: А докер из-под какого юзера запускается?

Comment: С компа, с админа

Comment: Тогда проверьте, что у этого админа есть права перезаписывать файлы, владельцем которых является www-data. Ну и ещё следует проверить пути, по которым эти файлы записываются.